# Linux: Could not start the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex in TeXstudio

Tags: xetex, pdftex, compiling, linux

I just installed LaTeX with `sudo apt install texlive-full` in addition to TeXstudio using the same method. When I try to build and compile any of my existing `.tex` files using PdfLaTeX I get the following message:

`Error: Could not start the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "file".tex`

The file`/usr/texbin/xelatex` is the only file within the `/usr/texbin` directory, so if I change the default compiler in TeXstudio to XeLaTeX the document will build. But if I want to use PdfLaTeX, do I have to tell TeXstudio where to look for the compiler? If so, how do I find the correct path?

I know this is a common problem on Mac, since users (even root user if I remember correctly) have no permission to write to either `/system`, `/bin`, `/sbin` or `/usr`. AFAIK this should not be an issue on Linux.

Comment: It should be `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/texbin`. On Linux there should be *no* `/usr/texbin` directory.